# How to run multiple yo angular-fullstack applications on same server and port?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, yo

I have a development server where I test my applications. I want to simultaneously run multiple yo angular-fullstack applications on that server in different sub-directeries. Eg: example.com/project1 should take me to first project and example.com/project2 should take me to second project. I tried creating an express application at root level and running that after adding separate route for each project like,
app.use('/project1', require('project1')); but it's not working because the compressed js and css files are not getting included.

Answer (score 0):

```
// REQUIRE
var path = require('path');

/* ... */

// ROUTES
app.get('/PROJ-1', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'PROJECT-1-PATH', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/PROJ-2', function (req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'PROJECT-2-PATH', 'index.html'));
});
```

I think this will works..

Comment: path.resolve just resolves the path segments into an absolute path. I have full-fledged applications which have their own routes in these sub folders. And when you use yo angular-js fullstack, and compile your app, there will be no index.html inside the root folder.

Comment: @pradeeshKumar did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck in the same situation

Comment: @Pablo If you are using Yo angular-full-stack, you will need to make multiple configuration changes including the path of the view files for each application. app.get will actually work if you do that for each and every application.